# Submit Job in Spark using Yarn Cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I am unable to submit the job in yarn cluster.The job is running fine under `yarn-client` option. When submit it to `yarn-cluster` only this log is coming multiple times.

```
Application report for application_1421828570504_0002 (state: ACCEPTED)
```

and got failed with the following exception.

```
diagnostics: Application application_1421828570504_0002 failed 10 times due to AM Container for app
attempt_1421828570504_0002_000010 exited with  exitCode: 1 due to: Exception from container-launch: org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: 
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException:
```

Comment: Welcome! As far as I understand, the exception is telling you that something exited with a non-zero exit code. Unless you get lucky and someone comes up with a good guess, I think you need to look at the logs and figure out _what_ failed and hopefully also _why_.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the logs of your application:

```
> yarn logs --applicationId application_1421828570504_0002
```

This will yield some debug information of the actual run within the spark containers.
Since it is running locally but not on the cluster my wild guess would be a missing SparkContext definition. Have a look at my [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33935065/1519186) for a fix.